# How can I calculate the final price of the product as the price of a unity times its quantity in a group ? Magento 1

Tags: product, magento-1, price

In my Magento store,a product has an attribute about the quantity of this product in a box,on the checkout is showing the price of the unity. How can I set its final price as the price of the unity times the quantity in a box ? (think as a box of shoes and it shows the price of the unity and the price of a box with many pairs, I want that the final price will be the box with many pairs inside)

[image: Price on catalog page]

[image: Price on checkout page]

[image: The price here must be R$1476 (the total price of the box)]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not clear where are you want to display this price and difficult to advise anything concrete about inject your logic, but you can use following logic to retrieve price for box:

```
/** @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */
$boxQty = $product->getData('box_qty_attribute');
if ($boxQty) {
    $boxPrice = $product->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice($boxQty, $product);
}
```